# doubble scroll bar on wordpress home page

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a WordPress website and I changed some CSS with Custom CSS Plugin  to adjust the position of the Footer. Here my CSS Changes:

```
.page-id-736 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-1981 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-2005 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-1989 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-1992 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-1997 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3318 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3339 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3345 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3348 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3351 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3354 .main-title {
  visibility: visible;
  display: none;
}

.page-id-736 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-1981 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-2005 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-1989 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-1992 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-1997 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3318 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3339 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3345 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3348 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3351 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-3354 .main-title + .breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.hentry__content .page-box p {
  display: none;
}

.comment {
  display: none;
}

.col-xs-12.form-group {
  display: none;
}

#comments.comments-post-1 {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-2362 .footer {
  margin: -45px;
}

.page-id-2362 .row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

and this is what my homepage looks like now:
[image]

Could someone please help me? 
Thanks,
Nico

Comment: it will be helpful if you could share the site URL...

Comment: I am sorry but at the moment for some reason it is not possible for me. The Screenshot is showing the page from Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your **footer has a -45px margin** on it. 
I think you were looking to limit this vertically.

so it should be **margin-top: -45px on your footer**.

Then you can remove the **overflow-x: hidden; from your body .boxed-container{}**
which is why the second scroll bar is appearing ( once you have defined a scroll behavior this is your problem ) just removing the overflow-x on the body .boxed-container will solve your problem but the footer having that -45px margin is what is the root cause of all your problems.

Comment: Hi @Ideatron, Thank you 1000 Times! you solved both problems. I changed " margin: -45px;" to " margin-top: -45px;" and the Problems are gone.

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

How could it help with the power of the code in question? If you can not share the URL of your site (understandable), at least share enough code with which we can recreate the situation / problem and be able to respond accordingly.